# Mouse hover like feel in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

I am new to iOS development. Sorry for any mistakes.

How can I get something in iOS similar to mouse hover and a button changing its color.

Do I need to use touch events or slide events for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the touchstart and touchend events. They are very responsive and act exactly as you would think. I apologize, you are not talking web. Either way, there should be touchevents in cocoa. I use Titanium, which accesses native methods via javascript and there are touchevents so I would know there are in cocoa. Check the documentation on the best manner in which to use those.

Depending on your desired effect you may want to use gestures as well. But if you are looking to mimic hover, a touchstart/end is what you want.